# "No space left on device" error but there is space

Tags: 18.04, disk-usage

This is Ubuntu 18.04. Please help to figure out the problem.

[image]

Comment: You also need to check for the amount of inodes available.

Comment: What is the output of `df -hi` (this will get us the inode information)?  Please also copy/paste the output as text and don't take screenshots of text and edit it into your question.

Comment: Thanks guys, it's inodes. I did create lots of 0-byte files in one of the directories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though you might not be out of actual space, you might be out of `inodes`.

Check the output of `df -hi` - if you've consumed all your inodes that explains the "no space left on device" problem.